# How to secure webapplication configuration file

Tags: linux, file, security, configuration, content-management-system

I need a book or an article about secure configuration of web applications (like drupal) that contain important information such as database username and password.
I found this link: [vbulletin](http://www.vbulletin.com/docs/html/main/securing_vbulletin_config) but I need more links for secure passwords and more about configuration file security.

Any body can help me?

Answer (score 0):

For securing drupal please visit the related site at https://drupal.org/security/secure-configuration